# How can I run React/Next based code downloaded from github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I downloaded zip file from https://github.com/prgrms-web-devcourse/Team_Price_Offer_FE
and unzipped it.

I tried to run that program is Visual Studio Code, so I entered command `npm start` but it didn't work.

```
Team_Price_Offer_FE-devel % npm start

> start
> next start

sh: next: command not found

sh: next: command not found
```

```
Team_Price_Offer_FE-devel % next start
zsh: command not found: next
```

Sorry my English is not good and my question may not be challenging; however, I can't get the program to start.

This is the code I used to install which also did not work.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm install node-sass@4.7.2
```

Comment: try `npm run dev` ^^

Comment: or `npm run build && npm run start`

Comment: install the dependencies first by running : 
npm install 
in the root of the project

Comment: First check you have the environment `node -v` and `npm -v` 
- Install the project dependencies `npm install`
- Once the installation is complete `npm start`
- Make sure to navigate to the root directory of the downloaded project

Answer (score 0):

When downloading a zip folder from Github, it is important to also load the node modules. Node modules can be very large and are therefore usually not added to the folder.

To download the node module from the package.json,
run

```
npm install
```

or

```
npm i
```

When the node_modules are successfully downloaded we can run our app
with

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need node and a package manager running in your computer, like npm or yarn (there are others)

Then, install all the dependencies widh (sample with npm)

```
npm install
```

And then go to package.json file and there are all the availabre commands for that project, in the script property, for this case:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
  "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
  "lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
  "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ./src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
},
```

To run those commands you can execute (sample with npm)

```
npm run <name of the script>
```

Samples:

```
npm run dev

npm run build

npm run start
```

And so on...